# Regular Expressions - How to identify a subset of a matched string

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I'm very unfamiliar with Regular Expressions and I need a way to identify a subset of a matched string.

I asked a question previously about [how to parse a string to extract date range values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092909/how-to-parse-a-string-to-extract-year-range-values). One of the answers I received was very useful and pretty much gave me everything I needed to solve the problem at hand.

Part of the answer was this regular expression:

```
string pattern = @"\b(?<Year1>\d{4})(-(?<Year2>\d{2,4}))?\b";
```

This pattern allows me to identify the first and second year substrings in the string I'm comparing, with `<Year1>` and `<Year2>`, and in code all i need to do is:

`searchTermMatch.Groups["Year1"].Value`

However, I now need to identify the first part of the string. So if the string is

> ThingOne ThingTwo 2006-2007 S12 RP

I need to be able to isolate "ThingOne ThingTwo" (which are only alphabetical characters - no numbers) the same as I can for "2006" & "2007".

I've tried changing the pattern to

```
string pattern = @"\b(<FirstPart>?<Year1>\d{4})(-(?<Year2>\d{2,4}))?\b";
```

but that didn't work.. so I'm looking to see if somebody could point out how I can achieve the result I need? Thanks.

Comment: To help us answer your question better you need to describe what the valid values for "Thing1" and "Thing2" are. Are they alphanumeric, just letters, just numbers, punctuation, etc.?

Comment: They are just letters. I'll update the question to reflect

Comment: This doesn’t look language-agnostic to me: the examples are not just regexes, but from a specific language. Why then the language-agnostic tag?

Comment: @tchrist, I kind of debated whether to include that tag or not. The core point of the question is the regex pattern, which in itself is language agnostic. For the sake of argument, can you identify the language based on the limited code snippets you see?

Comment: the @ sign kinda gives it away, eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@"^(?<FirstPart>.+?)(?<Year1>\d{4})(-(?<Year2>\d{2,4}))?\b"
```

The syntax works because matches in Regexps are noted by brackets. The naming syntax (which is BTW not supported in all languages) is `(?<name_of_match>pattern)`. So here we get three named matches:

- *FirstPart* will match `.+?` = any character repeated more then once but not more times then necessary
- *Year1* will match `\d{4}` = any digit character four times
- *Year2* will match `\d{2,4}` = any digit repeated from two to four times

Also notice the added `^` character at the beginning - it means start at the beginning of the line.

Comment: thanks Jakub, this *almost* works but not quite. `FirstPart` returns "Thing1 Thing2 2006-", where I need it to return just "Thing1 Thing2". `Year1` returns "2007" when it should return "2006". Any ideas?

Comment: Ah okay, the you need to use lazy matching. I'll update the answer.

Comment: +1: I think you meant `^` at the beginning without the `\b\`, i.e., @"^(?<FirstPart>.+?)(?<Year1>\d{4})(-(?<Year2>\d{2,4}))?\b"

Comment: I guess that it depends on the implementation (or host) language - I assumed that the `\b` was a RegExp delimeter in this case (as I have no clue on what the language might possibly be ;).

Comment: The language is C# (.NET), so there are no regex delimiters.  `\b` is a word boundary (http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html); you should leave it in place, and add the new part before it.